# How to delete a struct from an array without leaving a gap?

Tags: solidity

I want to delete a struct from an array.  The order doesn't matter to me so I want to do something like following where you take the last element in the array to replace the element I want to delete so that there are no gaps in the array.

```
mapping (address => File[]) myFiles;

function deleteFile(uint _index) public {
    require(_index >= 0, "The index cannot be a negative number");
    
    File[] memory files = myFiles[msg.sender];
    require(_index < files.length, "The index is out of bound");
        
    if (files.length == 1) {
        files.pop();
    } else {
        File memory file = files[files.length - 1];
        files[_index] = files;
        files.pop();
    }
}
```

However, `pop` is not available for struct arrays. I also cannot use `files.length --` since `length` is read-only. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You are using a memory array, if you used a storage reference instead it should work: `File[] storage files = myFiles[msg.sender]`. Another problem you will have with memory arrays is that changes are on memory and will be discarded if they are not explicitly saved to storage.

Comment: @Ismael most of the answers on the link you provided use `array.length -- ` which doesn't seem to work anymore. Is there no way to delete an element from an array without iterating through the entire array if I wanted to leave no gap?

Comment: To delete the last item from use `array.pop()`, it works for array in storage.